# How to reload all the tabs using angular4

Tags: angular, google-chrome

I am using angular 4 and I want to reload all the tabs in the browser(google chrome).
I am using the following code but it only reload the current tab.

```html
location.reload();
```

Comment: I did not understand can you tell more and post your code in https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Is it any way that we can reload all the tabs that are currently open in a browser using java script or angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually seem to be developing a Chrome extension, so my answer is based on this assumption.

Unless you have no control over JavaScript running in other tabs, you won't be able to refresh these tabs due to security constraints. Imagine it would be possible to access other tabs, then any webpage could easily steal any sensitive data by just changing forms' action property to any hacker controlled host.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(null, function(tabs) {
for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    chrome.tabs.update(tabs[i].id, {url: tabs[i].url});
  }
});
```

[Check this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-getAll)

I have one question, are you trying to develop any chrome extension?